# Allow classes in a dependency to load test resources from my project's classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath

NOTE:  There are many similar questions on StackOverflow.  The distinction is that these questions refer to the usage of another project's resources within their own project.  I'd like to know how to refer to my *own* project's resources from within a class that exists in another project which my own project depends upon.  For example:

I have a Maven project (A) with a structure like this:

```
src
  test
    java
      com
        mycompany
          myproject
            SimpleTest.java
    resources
      com
        mycompany
          myproject
            pictures
              mountain.jpg
pom.xml
```

In the pom.xml file for project A I have a resource entry like this:

```xml
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/com/mycompany/myproject/pictures</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Project A also has a dependency on another Maven project (B).  At runtime the SimpleTest.java class in project A will be launched directly from the file system (not from a JAR or WAR file) using the following command:

```
C:\path\to\project\A\mvn clean test
```

This will download project B as a JAR file from my company's Nexus repository, build project A, and run the tests in SimpleTest.java via the Surefire plugin using TestNG.

Let's pretend there's a class in project B called 'Helper' which contains an 'upload' function like this:

```java
public class Helper {
  public static void upload(String filename) {
    Class clazz = this.getClass();
    ClassLoader classLoader = clazz.getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    // TODO: upload file
  }
}
```

Now let's pretend that one of the tests in SimpleTest.java calls Helper.upload using "mountain.jpg" as an argument.

Currently inputStream ends up being null.  However, the upload function *DOES* work if the filename parameter matches one of the resource files inside project B.

It appears to me that the classes in project B (IE: Helper.class) do not have the resources from project A on their classpaths even though project A is currently running.  This seems counter-intuitive to me.  I would like all of the test resources in project A to be available from any class when running tests in project A.  How can I make this happen?

Comment: This should work. Have you checked content of the 'target/test-classes' directory of the project A? Is 'mountain.jpg' there?

Comment: Yes, Maven reads my testResources entry and adds the mountain.jpg file to the test-classes directory.

Comment: Maybe that's just because of modifications of original code before posting to SO, but you've missed `resources` directory between `test` and `com` in the `testResources` configuration. Also `upload` method is static, but you're using `this` reference - this won't compile...

Comment: Nice catches!  Yes, it looks like I oversimplified the real issue and made some mistakes and assumptions.  It turns out that there are more things in play here which are probably relevant.  I'll refactor this question when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Just put Helper in project A and call it from B. Make it return InputStream, instead of doing something with resources, so that B could perform test actions with it.

Note, that [Class.getResourceAsStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) might be easier to use.

Comment: Well, what would be the point of project B then?  The idea here is that project B is a separate framework that performs common tasks (IE: uploading) for several other projects.  As a last resort I suppose it could be required that these other projects pass in an existing InputStream instead of asking project B to open one for them.

Comment: Probably there is indeed no need in B. You test project A, you have resources there. Why do you need B to to test A?

Comment: I've edited answer to clarify how B should use Helper class from the project being tested.